# Docker --ssh default Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ssh-keys

I am trying to build a docker image with `--ssh default` on MacOS but it is not working.
The same build work on Linux.

```Dockerfile
//Dockerfile

#syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app

RUN chown -R node.node /app

RUN mkdir ~/.ssh/ && ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git+ssh://git@github.com/account_name/repo.git

CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

When I run

```
docker build --ssh default -t my_image .
```

I get the error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

I have my ssh key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` on my local machine and it is working outside docker.

If I try to run in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I get the error:

```
cat: /root/.ssh/id_rsa No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Docker is not copying the file from `~/.ssh/`.

When using the default configuration `--ssh default` you need to add your keys to your local SSH agent.

You can check `ssh-add -L` locally to see if the public keys are visible to the agent.

If they are not, try to run `ssh-add -K`.

References:

https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/build-secrets-and-ssh-forwarding-in-docker-18-09-ae8161d066

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254468/macos-sierra-doesn-t-seem-to-remember-ssh-keys-between-reboots

Answer (score 1):

Just a small update to the previous answer.

On the Mac `ssh-add -K` is **deprecated**, so use `ssh-add --apple-use-keychain` instead